# A way to apply Kalman filtering on each BLE device separately using python

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, kalman-filter

I am trying to get filtered RSSI values of each BLE beacon using Kalman filtering. I cannot use a single instance of kalman filtering on all BLE devices, how to map or assign a instance of kalman filter for each BLE device. I know it has something to do with maps but cannot figure out how to implement it.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from bluepy.btle import Scanner
from kalman import KalmanFilter
scanner = Scanner().withDelegate(ScanDelegate())
blemacid = ["d7:b1:41:09:ca:c2","ed:9d:41:19:4c:43","fe:98:f1:d3:85:4f","de:0d:34:4d:66:5e"]

kalmanfilter=map(KalmanFilter(0.008,0.1),blemacid)

while(True):
   devices=scanner.scan(3.0)
   for device in devices:
      if device.addr in blemacid:
         print ("DEV={} RSSI ={}".format(device.addr,kalmanfilter.filter(device.rssi)))
```

the kalman filter implementation is here [kalman filer](https://github.com/Kinar-Usha/kalmanpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `map` is the correct solution for this problem. An instance of the filter stored in a dictionary and keyed by the device address would seem a better solution. For example:

```py
from bluepy.btle import Scanner
from kalman import KalmanFilter
scanner = Scanner().withDelegate(ScanDelegate())
blemacid ={"d7:b1:41:09:ca:c2": KalmanFilter(0.008,0.1),
           "ed:9d:41:19:4c:43": KalmanFilter(0.008,0.1),
           "fe:98:f1:d3:85:4f": KalmanFilter(0.008,0.1),
           "de:0d:34:4d:66:5e": KalmanFilter(0.008,0.1)}

while(True):
   devices=scanner.scan(3.0)
   for device in devices:
      if device.addr in blemacid.keys():
         print("DEV={} RSSI ={}".format(device.addr,blemacid[device.addr].filter(device.rssi)))
```

I would also be careful that `device.addr` returns the address in lowercase, the same as you have in `blemacid` keys so the address comparison works correctly.

Comment: thanks for the solution. We ended doing the same way.